# Use ASP.NET Core Identity with Blazor Server razor pages

Tags: .net, authentication, blazor-server-side, identity

I'm trying to implement authorization on my **Blazor Server App** and I would like to use **Identity** because if offers to me all the **roles and other features** ready to use.
I follow a tutorial like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B0_gM-wBlmE&t=2812s
adapting all the pages with my app but doesn't work, it gives to me this error: **blazor SignInAsync have This Error 'Headers are read-only, response has already started.'**

I don't know much about **.net** but I think that the tutorial I followed is not compatible with **Signal R and Blazor Server.**

My scope is to create a **basic authentication** with my **personal razor pages** (no scaffolding) and use the identity functionalities: **allow accessing certain pages only for certains roles...**
Any suggestions? Provide me also **links to tutorial** (as long as they work)...

Comment: [Polite] "I don't know much about .net but I think that the tutorial I followed is not compatible with Signal R and Blazor Server." Why did you choose to follow a tutorial that is not Blazor specific when there are any number of articles and tutorials on the subject that are.  Search "Blazor identity authentication" and follow one of those.

Answer (score 0):

The error you're encountering, "Headers are read-only, response has already started," typically occurs in Blazor Server applications when there's an issue with the timing of an authentication-related operation, particularly during the SignInAsync operation. It often indicates that you're trying to modify the response headers after the response has already been sent to the client.

To implement authentication and authorization with Identity in your Blazor Server App without using scaffolding, you can follow these steps:

Add Identity to Your Project:

Ensure you have added the required Identity packages to your project. You can do this using the .NET CLI or Visual Studio's NuGet Package Manager.
shell

```
dotnet add package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore
dotnet add package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI
Configure Identity:
```

In your Startup.cs file, configure Identity services. Here's a minimal example:
csharp

```
services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

Create Razor Pages for Authentication:

Create your own Razor pages for registration, login, and other authentication-related tasks. You can customize these pages to match your application's design and requirements.
Configure Authentication and Authorization:

Use the [Authorize] attribute on your Razor pages to restrict access to authenticated users or specific roles. For example:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
public class AdminPageModel : PageModel
{
    // Your code here
}
```

Customize User Registration and Login:

Implement your custom registration and login logic in your Razor pages. You can use the SignInManager and UserManager provided by Identity to manage user authentication.
Handle Authentication State in Blazor Components:

Use Blazor components like AuthorizeView to manage the UI based on the user's authentication status and role. You can display different content to authenticated users and guests.

Comment: Yes, but the PasswordSignInAsync method gives me the errror I mentioned in the questions... So I think it is not compatible with Signal R blazor Server